# pyqgis: issue with copying attributes of a features to a new created one

Tags: pyqgis

Context: the script selects features from a layer which overlaps another one above a certain percentage and creates a new layer with these selected features. I do not manage to copy the attributes from the attributes table, only the ID is reported.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

#for Severity
feats_lyr1 = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

#for Basins800
feats_lyr2 = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

selected_feats = []

print "processing..."

for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area1 = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            area2 = feat2.geometry().area()
            crit =area1/area2
            if crit > 0.8:
                selected_feats.append(feat2)

epsg = layers[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           "mem_layer",
                           "memory")



lyr = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(selected_feats):
    feat.setAttributes(selected_feats[i].attributes())
    lyr.addFeatures([feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
print "done..."
```

Comment: Your issue is because you need to create one field, with **QVariant**, for each one you want to appear in attributes table of memory layer. Defined uri only allows id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because you need to create one field, with **QVariant**, for each one you want to appear in attributes table of memory layer. Defined **uri** only allows **id** field. For instance, at following image you can observe that attributes table of polygon8 (equivalent to your **Basins800**) has several fields.

[image]

Suppose that I want to copy 'values' field in attributes table of resulting memory layer (order must be considered), I need these additional lines in my code:

```
.
.
.
field = QgsField("values", QVariant.Int)
lyr.addAttributes([field])
mem_layer.updateFields()
.
.
.
```

Adding them to your code, it is as follow:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

#for Severity
feats_lyr1 = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

#for Basins800
feats_lyr2 = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

selected_feats = []

print "processing..."

for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area1 = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            area2 = feat2.geometry().area()
            crit =area1/area2
            if crit > 0.6:
                selected_feats.append(feat2)

epsg = layers[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           "mem_layer",
                           "memory")

lyr = mem_layer.dataProvider()

#added lines
field = QgsField("values", QVariant.Int)
lyr.addAttributes([field])
mem_layer.updateFields()
#######################

for i, feat in enumerate(selected_feats):
    feat.setAttributes(selected_feats[i].attributes())
    lyr.addFeatures([feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
print "done..."
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS (note that it was used crit > 0.6 with my shapefiles to get a result), it can be observed that attributes table of created memory layer has desired field.

[image]

If you want specific fields in your attributes table you need to extract them from **selected_feats[i].attributes()** matrix list. It is not too difficult. For instance, in Python Console I have:

```
>>>attributes = [ feat.attributes() for feat in selected_feats ]
>>>attributes
[[1.0, 43, 1351.0, 2330.0, 1, 280502186.97, 65657.871, 500, 27, u'my test', 3, 1], [6.0, 83, 1538.0, 1772.0, 6, 127035968.31, 46664.327, 20, 84, u'my test', 4, 1]]
```